# "IndexError when Parsing CSV in Python: Issue with Accessing Column Values"

Tags: python, html, backend

I am currently working on a Python script to parse a CSV file, and I'm encountering an 'IndexError' that I can't seem to resolve. I've tried a few approaches, but none have worked so far.

snippet:

```py
import csv

file_path = 'example.csv'

with open(file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # IndexError occurs in the line below
        value = row[3]
        # Rest of the code...
```

I expected to retrieve the value from the fourth column of each row without encountering any errors. However, I'm consistently getting an 'IndexError: list index out of range' at the line where I try to access row[3]. Despite checking the CSV file and confirming that it contains the expected number of columns, I haven't been able to identify the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Please add a few lines of your csv file so people can reproduce your problem.